# Fetch relational objects with PFQuery

Tags: ios, swift, pfquery

I have the following query. It goes to my `Posts` class and gets all posts into an an PFObject array of posts.

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
query.includeKey("bellongsToStyle")
query.includeKey("createdByUser")
query.whereKey("bellongsToStyle", containedIn: selectedStyles)
return query
```

It also includes all the data for inside those 2 pointer columns with the `includeKey` method. I can retrieve them so that is all good.

There is another column named `votedByUser` that is a relational column that adds users to each post if they voted on it.

Is there a way to retrieve the user objects related to each post with this query?

I know it wont happen with `includeKey`, but fundamentally I would like to be able to get all this data with this query.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say when you were saving an object in which you also assign an id which will be save into the **userID** in Parse.

To retrieve that object you will do :

```
var userObjectId =  PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
query.whereKey("userID", equalTo: userObjectId)
```